# Azure App Service - Spring Boot application stuck on startup

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I host Spring Boot web applications as Azure App Services, however one of the seems to be stuck in a loop on startup. The application is not accessible and it looks like it restarts every half a minute. There are no errors in the logs and restarting the App Service didn't help either.

Does someone have an idea why it is happening or how I could fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the jar will take more time to start with the default startup command. It could be because it scannes the file system for configuration files since it uses `-cp` command to start the `jar`.

```
java -cp app.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

I fixed this issue by providing a startup command in the AppService->Configuration->General Settings->Startup command

```
java -jar <path_of_jar>
```

Altenatevely you can check the container logs also Please refer the link below.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs]

If you are logging into a file, then you can SSH[Azure portal->AppService-> left side there is an SSH option ] to the container and `tail` the logs directly, but sometimes it is very hard to get into a container using ssh since it is not starting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.properties` should have:

```
logging.level=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.file=/home/LogFiles/boot.log
```

`boot.log` should give you more on what to hunt down next.

Comment: Tried /home/LogFiles/boot.log but found that adding the following to the web.config file worked instead -Dlogging.file=&quot;%HOME%\LogFiles\boot.log&quot;

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the problem. On default the App Service configuration was set up to use Jetty as web container instead of Tomcat. Probably the service tried to validate that the Jetty is up and running and since it wasn't the service kept restarting. 
Once I set the configuration to Tomcat the issue was solved.