# Azure spring boot app service keeps restarting

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I have spring boot app deployed to IIS / embedded tomcat as an azure app service. When the app service is started the app logs show a restart occurs (new pid) about every 10 minutes for the same instance. After 90 minutes it will eventually deploy successfully.
There’s nothing i can see from the embedded tomcat logs nor org.springframework logs suggesting any issue, however on occasion it can start in under 2 mins.

Where else can I look for startup errors and is there a way I can increase the app service startup time as I don’t know what is causing it to restart?

Comment: You can refer to [SpringBoot applications keeps rebooting all the time (restart loop) - spring.devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812812/springboot-applications-keeps-rebooting-all-the-time-restart-loop-spring-dev), [springboot app on azure app service stops right after start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989407/springboot-app-on-azure-app-service-stops-right-after-start) and [springboot session timeout setting in azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/481452/springboot-session-timeout-setting-in-azure-app-se.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set  the configuration to Tomcat from App service> configuration >General setting
based on your required version as below :

[image]

Also Thanks to  [Sreyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938284/sreyas) Posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631517/azure-app-service-spring-boot-application-stuck-on-startup) as an answer to help other community members.

"Sometimes the jar will take more time to start with the default startup command. It could be because it scannes the file system for configuration files since it uses  `-cp`  command to start the  `jar`.

```
java -cp app.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

I fixed this issue by providing a startup command in the AppService->Configuration->General Settings->Startup command

```
java -jar <path_of_jar>
```

Altenatevely you can check the container logs also Please refer the link below. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs]

If you are logging into a file, then you can SSH[Azure portal->AppService-> left side there is an SSH option ] to the container and  `tail`  the logs directly, but sometimes it is very hard to get into a container using ssh since it is not starting properly."

For more information please refer this on going discussion over MS Q&A for similar issue: [Azure app service restart loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/575076/azure-app-service-restart-loop.html) & Microsoft Documentation: [HttpPlatformHandler Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference) .